# Remove numbers in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to remove the numbers in the bibliography. For example:

> FERREIRA, L. P. (Org.). O fonoaudiólogo e a escola. São Paulo: Summus, 1991.

without number. I am trying `\bibitem [] {Askey}`, but `[]` appears in the document. Can someone tell me how this is done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
Resultados obtidos foram utilizado: Askey (1985),$^{\cite{Askey}}$
\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
   \bibitem [] {Askey} ASKEY, R.; WILSON, J. 
     \emph{Some Basic Hypergeometric Polynomial that Generalize Jacobi Polynomial}. 
      Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, v. 54, p. 1-55, 1985. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Andrew \begin{document}

Resultados obtidos foram utilizado: Askey (1985),$^{\cite{Askey}}$

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem [] {Askey} ASKEY, R.; WILSON, 
J.
\emph{Some Basic Hypergeometric Polynomial that Generalize Jacobi Polynomial}.
Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, v. 54, p. 1-55, 1985.

\end{document}

Comment: This should go into your question. I have added it in for you, together with a `\documentclass` as this is also needed. As I said, if you give people something to work from they are much more likely to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on how you have set up your document and how you create your bibliogrphy etc (are you using bibtex, biblatex, ...?).

Any way one solution, which may or may not be appropriate is to add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \c@chapter\z@ \c@section\z@\let\chaptername\relax
  \section*{References}\list
  {}{\settowidth\labelwidth{}\leftmargin\labelwidth
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
  \itemsep\z@\parsep\z@\topsep\z@\parskip\z@
  \usecounter{enumi}}
  \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\makeatletter
```

Actually, this solution makes the bibliography more compact, which you mightn't like.

Another solution, that it closer is spirit to what you tried, is to modify `\bibitem`. If you look at the definition of `\bibitem` (using, for example, `\show`), you will see that it calls `\@bibtem` and this is where the `\item` command comes from. Hence, you can get what you want with the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item[]%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string \bibcite {#1}{\the\value{\@listctr }}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
```

The difference between these two approaches is the indentation of the bibliography entries. The first attempt produces

[image]

whereas the second gives you

[image]

The first approach is the more robust and the second may have unintended side-effects, not least because it doesn't cater for the optional argument that `\bibitem` accepts.

Comment: I used the first one and works very well =).  Thanks a lot!!